# Android menu modification?

Tags: android, xml, layout, menu

just wondering if it's possible to modify the android menu layout. Eg, with different color backgrounds, font size, etc.

I know we can add icons, but I was hoping for something more.

Also, can we make the menu display more than 6 items a time?

How can this be achieved? Are there perhaps some XML tags?

If anyone has a link to all the different XML tags for me, that would be awesome too.

Regards,

Rich.

Comment: duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193348/custom-options-menu-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478418/android-how-can-i-set-a-listener-to-the-menubutton) post I suggest you to use a SlidingDrawer(or any custom view) on MENU key press

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        //MENU pressed  start your SlidingDrawer (or any custom View) here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope it helps.